# Make a JQuery disabled button enabled with proper styles

Tags: jquery-ui, button

I have a JQuery Button, disabled by default and I need to enable it on certain event.

My problem is that when I just simply remove the attribute 'disabled' the button maintains the disabled jquery css styles.

I removed them by hand:

```
$('[id$=btnDowloadXLS]').removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("ui-state-disabled").removeClass("ui-button-disabled");
```

But, then the button is not the same as an active button, onMouseDown it doesn't take the proper style.

I figured out this solution

```
 $('[id$=btnDowloadXLS]').button({ disabled: false });
```

which I think **creates again** the JQuery button.

My question is: is there a cleaner, proper way to re-enable a button and that the button gets the proper/by-default enabled styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI buttons have [enable and disable methods](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#methods) that you can call to enable or disable the button:

```
$("#mybutton").button("enable"); // or .button("disable");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the *Methods* tab of [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/):

```
.button("enable");
```

If you want to toggle it using a Boolean (e.g. `enabled`), this should also work ([documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-option)):

```
.button("option", "disabled", !enabled);
```

Comment: thanks, the first answer is what I was needing.
I haven't tried the second but can be useful in the future.